# Synchronized hashmap read-only access in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, synchronized, readonly

In Java, there are 3 threads that want to access (read-only) an immutable hashmap to do something. Is `SynchronizedMap` class below the fastest solution for that purpose? If not, then what would be faster to use?

```
import com.carrotsearch.hppc.IntObjectMap;
import com.carrotsearch.hppc.IntObjectOpenHashMap;

public class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final IntObjectMap<int[]> map = new IntObjectOpenHashMap<int[]>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            map.put(i, new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5});
        }

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];

        class SynchronizedMap {

            private final Object syncObject = new Object();

            public final int[] read(int i) {

                final int[] value;

                synchronized (syncObject) {

                    // code that reads-only immutable map object
                    value = map.get(i);

                }

                return value;

            }
        }

        final SynchronizedMap syncMap = new SynchronizedMap();

        class AccessMap implements Runnable {

            private int id;
            AccessMap(int index) { id = index; }

            public void run() {

                // code that reads-only immutable map object like this:
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {

                    final int[] array = syncMap.read(i);

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++)
                        System.out.println(id + ": " + array[j] + " ");

                }

            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new AccessMap(i) {});
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
            try {
                threads[i].join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If the map is read-only, I don't think you have to do any synchronization at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is SynchronizedMap class below the fastest solution for that purpose?

No.  If the `HashMap` is truly immutable/read-only then a `volatile Map<...>` is the way to go.

```
volatile IntObjectMap<int[]> readOnlyMap = new IntObjectOpenHashMap<int[]>();
```

If you are starting your threads *after* your map is built then you don't even need the `volatile`.  The only time you would need the `volatile` is if you are swapping in a new map that is being accessed by currently running threads.

```
final IntObjectMap<int[]> readOnlyMap = new IntObjectOpenHashMap<int[]>();
```

Comment: I concur.  Here's a good discussion: http://jeremymanson.blogspot.com/2008/11/what-volatile-means-in-java.html

Comment: Good point @SophieSperner.  It was more for posterity then your specific implementation.

Comment: Q: Back to Louis Wasserman's question - if nothing will *change* ... then why do you need "synchronized" *OR* "volatile"?

Comment: You need `volatile` if you are creating a new `HashMap` which is shared by already running threads @paulsm4.  It's about order of operations and constructor visibility.  In her case, she is creating the threads afterwards so no synchronization is necessary.